# How to set a php variable from a sql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

Im trying to set a php variable to a field and row of a database. I use:

```
$moped_select = "SELECT * FROM moped_details WHERE moped_ID='$_SESSION[moped_number]'";
$selected_moped = $db->query($moped_select);
if (($selected_moped->rowCount()) >= 1) {
  foreach($selected_moped as $row){
    $moped_rate = $row['rate'];
}
```

This doesn't set $moped_rate as the field and row, I have seen other people use this line before and it works. Whats even weirder is that I use a similar line to this to place data in a form. Which looked like this (keep in mind it is inside a foreach(x as $row) loop:

```
 echo "<td>".$row['model']."</td>";
```

This echos out correctly so im kinda confused why  Any suggestions would be appreciated <3.

Comment: just like what the manual says: _`For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.`_, so its unreliable

Comment: since you're just expected one row, just simply change and use `->fetchColumn` and test for emptiness

Comment: So what exactly do I change? do I change rowCount to fetchColumn?

Comment: See: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count

Answer (score 0):

Your code should as below

```
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost','username','password');
$moped_select = "SELECT * FROM moped_details WHERE moped_ID=?";
$selected_moped = $db->prepare($moped_select);
$db->execute([$_SESSION["moped_numberf"]]);


if(($db>rowCount()) >= 1) {
  while($row=$selectedmoped->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
    $moped_rate = $row['rate'];
}
```